# Version control organization for large .NET solutions

Tags: .net, version-control, svn

I'm trying to come up with a better way to organize my C# projects on SVN. The .NET solution for my main GUI has about 28 class library projects. These libraries fall into two categories. Some of them are general and could be used in many other places, and others are specific to the project our company is currently working on. My approach has been to name the general project libraries starting with our company name, something like this:

```
CompanyName.Controls
CompanyName.IO
CompanyName.MathLibrary
CompanyName.UnitTestHelpers
```

And the library projects that are specific to a project are named starting with the project name. So for example if the project was called ABC. Some of the library projects might be called:

```
ABC.ConfigFile
ABC.ConfigFile.UnitTests
ABC.Packets
ABC.Packets.UnitTests
ABC.Data
ABC.Data.UnitTests
```

Then there might be several GUIs that use some combination of these library projects. My current approach when I need to create a new GUI is to add a new project to this large solution. Then the whole solution and related projects are put on SVN in one place.

```
svn/
   ABC.GUIs/
      trunk/
         CompanyName.Controls/
         CompanyName.IO/
         CompanyName.MathLibrary/
         ABC.ConfigFile/
         ABC.SomeGUI/
         ABC.SomeOtherGUI/
         ...
      branches/
      tags/
```

I know this isn't the best approach. Here is where I'm trying to come up with a better way, especially for sharing library projects between GUIs.

Here are the ideas I've come up with.

1. Add each project to it's own solution and add each of these to SVN.

```
svn/
   CompanyName.Controls/
      trunk/
      branches/
      tags/
   CompanyName.IO/
      trunk/
      branches/
      tags/
   CompanyName.MathLibrary/
      trunk/
      branches/
      tags/
   ABC.ConfigFile/
      trunk/
      branches/
      tags/
...
```

If one project depended on another project then it would use svn externals to reference it. Then each GUI would be its own solution and use svn externals for each library project it used.

This approach seems kinda overwhelming though.

2. Store the company-wide general libraries in one spot on svn, all of the project specific libraries in another spot, and each GUI in it's own place.

```
svn/
   CompanyLibraries/
      trunk/
         CompanyName.Controls/
         CompanyName.IO/
         CompanyName.MathLibrary/
      branches/
      tags/
   ABCLibraries/
      trunk/
         ABC.ConfigFile/
      branches/
      tags/
   ABC.SomeGUI/
      trunk/
      branches/
      tags/
   ABC.SomeOtherGUI/
      trunk/
      branches/
      tags/
...
```

This solution feels a lot better. I think I would still use SVN externals when depending on other projects.

Are there any other approaches or suggestions? Does it make sense to have the trunk, branches, and tags folders under the company and project libraries like I have?

Comment: Which way allows you to most easily find things?  Folder structure is not architecture, so you can arrange these folders any way you want.

Comment: If you start a new project then switch to git.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, you wrote

> This solution feels a lot better

for an approach which looked pretty horrible to me.

But first things first. I think the missing piece here is getting clarity about an appropriate **versioning and release strategy** - which is tool-agnostic. Then, as a second step, one can decide about the repo structure which supports this strategy best.

Let me assume all of the libraries/assemblies named "ABC.*" are versioned and released together, with a single, common version number? Then all those libs should be under a common `trunk` folder, which lets you tag them together whenever a new version is deployed, branch them together etc. Giving each library own trunk/tag/branch folders will heavily increase management efforts with no real benefit.

Concerning your "Company.*" libs, even if they are used outside your project ABC, you need to decide if they shall be versioned and released under the same common version label with ABC, or if you want to version and release them independently (maybe in more frequent release intervals). For the former situation, your first `svn` repo structure looks pretty sufficient for me, no need to make things more complicated than necessary.

If, however, you want to release the "Company.*" libs more frequently, for each library or combination of library with its own life cycle, separate trunk/tag/branch folders make sense. But don't expect this additional structure coming for free, it will require more configuration management effort than the first one.

So in short, repo structure is not an end in itself, it is a means to an end. First clarify your goals, then structure accordingly, not the other way round.